# Why are arrays passed as arguments mutable but scalars are not?

Tags: raku

Got this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env raku
use v6;

multi blah (@arg) { @arg = 7; }
multi blah ($arg) { $arg = '3'; }

my @array = 1, 2, 3;
blah @array;
say @array;

my $string = 'onetwothree';
blah $string;
say $string;
```

Get this:

```
[7]
Cannot assign to a readonly variable or a value
  in sub blah at ./chop.raku line 5
  in block <unit> at ./chop.raku line 12
```

I found this behavior surprising, particularly the ability to change to the array outside of the scope of the function.

Can someone please explain why I can change an array argument passed to a function but not a scalar? And is there a way to make arrays read only when passed to a function? Is there any way to make a scalar passed to a function mutable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can someone please explain why I can change an array argument passed to a function but not a scalar?

Arguments passed to a function are read-only (by default; more on that below) and so generally can't be changed.  The reason that you can modify the `Array` is that `Array`s are, themselves, mutable (see the [Lists, sequences, and arrays](https://docs.raku.org/language/list) page in the docs for details).  This means that, even though you can't change the `Array` *itself*, you can still change the values **in** the `Array`.

> And is there a way to make arrays read only when passed to a function?

The [List](https://docs.raku.org/type/List) is Raku's immutable type for positional data (sort of; it's not deeply immutable, but that's beyond the scope here).  If you pass a `List` into a function, the function won't be able to modify the contents of that list.  For example, this code throws an error:

```raku
my @l is List = (1, 2, 3);
sub f(@var) { @var[1] = 42 }
f @l;
```

> Is there any way to make a scalar passed to a function mutable?

There are two ways, depending on what sort of mutability you want: you can use either the [`is rw` and `is copy` traits](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#index-entry-trait_is_rw).  For example, you might declare a function like so:

```raku
sub f($a is copy, $b is rw) {...}
```

That declaration allows `&f` to modify both `$a` and `$b`.  But for `$a`, `&f` is modifying its own local copy and won't have any effect on the value its callers see for `$a`.  With `$b`, however, `&f` is modifying shared state and any changes it makes to `$b` will be visible even outside the scope of `&f`.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. And I've been doing some reading about all this tonight: https://opensource.com/article/18/8/containers-perl-6  and https://uzluisf.gitlab.io/posts/2020/04/03/raku-containers/ are also very helpful. But this is something you can read about in the docs but it won't hit home until you actually start writing code and get some nasty surprises and unexplained errors.

Comment: Note that you can use "is copy" on arrays as well: `sub frobnicate(@a is copy) { @a.push: 42; say @a }; my @b = 666; frobnicate @b; say @b;  # [666 42] [666]`.  And hashes as well  :-)

Comment: You said there are 2 ways for mutating scalars via passing them to functions but what about `is raw`?

Comment: From the docs https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#Parameter_traits_and_modifiers. The is raw trait is automatically applied to parameters declared with a backslash or a plus sign as a "sigil", and may also be used to make normally sigiled parameters behave like these do. In the special case of slurpies, which normally produce an Array full of Scalars as described above, is raw will instead cause the parameter to produce a List. Each element of that list will be bound directly as raw parameter.